# Theme Customizer not loading JS for live preview

Tags: theme-development, functions, javascript, hooks, theme-customizer

I am currently working on adding options to the theme customizer. For the last two hours I have been trying to get the live preview working and I am trying figure out why my theme isn't loading the `theme-customizer.js` file needed for the live preview.

All of the options I have added to the theme-customizer work if I save it and then refresh the page. So I know it isn't an issue with the settings.

I currently have the hook to call the JS file within the `customize.php` file along with all of the settings for the customizer. I also have a separate `theme-enqueue.php` where I enqueue the other JS files for my theme.

Here is an example of the hook I am trying to call the JS file from within my `customize.php` file:

```
function mytheme_customize_preview_js() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme-customizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme-customizer.js', array( 'customize-preview' ), '20120187', true );
}
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'mytheme_customize_preview_js' );
```

When I check the loaded javascript files within chrome, it seems to load all of the ones I need except for this one. Can anyone shed some light on the situation?

Comment: do you want this script load in admin area?

Comment: Did you check if the path to your file is correct?

Comment: Why are you trying to load `theme-customizer.js`? That is not generally necessary for hooking into the Customize API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your script is loaded correctly, same function is used in twentytwelve ( but your script is inside the iframe) but i can be wrong (dont know excactly how your theme is construct, maybe it's a path related issue with multiple include)

[image]

to see the change with no refresh you have to you use the 'transport' arguments in  add_setting and get_setting in your customize_register function

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'my_setting', array( 'default' => 'setting_value', 'transport' => 'postMessage', ) );
```

This can be either 'refresh' (default) or 'postMessage'. Only set this to 'postMessage' if you are writing custom Javascript to control the Theme Customizer's live preview.

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'my_setting' )->transport = 'postMessage';
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're calling it from inside the init or admin_init Wordpress hook, whereas you should call it from within the after_setup_theme hook.

For example:

```
function mytheme_customize_preview_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme-customizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme-customizer.js', array( 'customize-preview' ), '20120187', true );
}
function my_after_setup_theme(){
    add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'mytheme_customize_preview_js' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_after_setup_theme' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact answer to the problem. But it helped me to solved the very problem we are discussing.

As using `'transport' => 'postMessage'`, I was not able to see previews lively. So I created new files using the [following code at Github](https://gist.github.com/tommcfarlin/d983d7b383b76e66e652)

I just copy pasted this code. Verified it and then tweaked it according to my requirements.
I know this is not the solution but it was the best availaible one for me.

Thanks to Tom McFarlin for the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
function mytheme_customize_preview_js() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme-customizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme-customizer.js', array( 'customize-preview' ), '20120187', true );
} 
add_action( 'admin_init', 'mytheme_customize_preview_js' );
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory context on why this would solve the OPs problem. Answers consisting of only a code block are rarely as good as they could be. If this answer would explain what an action hook is and why you suggest hooking into `admin_init`, it would of much better quality. That being said, note the existence of the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) action.